# Working with tuples and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I've taken tuple keys from a dictionary.  As of now, I've managed to get them into a list doing this:

```
dict = {(3,13):'gas', (11,4):'gas', (0,1):'food', (1,5):'food'}

list = []

for i in dict:
    if dict.get(i,0) == 'gas':
        list.append(i)
```

As part of an exercise, I need to be able to get into the tuples to use each (x,y) pair in a formula. How can I go about doing that?

So for example,  if `(3,1)` is the first value that i'm working with from my list, I want to be able to take each value out individually.  I would have the `3` go into my formula as an `x`, and `1` go into my formula as a `y`.

The only module that I can import is `math`, so I can use `sqrt`.

Comment: your list can be built with `[key for key, value in dictionary.items() if value == 'gas']`. Not sure what you are asking for however.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get into the tuples so I can use each x and y pair in a formula.

Comment: "get into the tuples" = "access each tuple element separately"? It's not clear what you want, maybe if you'd give a few examples it would help...

Comment: avoid naming the dictionary `dict`. As per the answer you just got, use `dic` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do tuple unpacking:

```
for i in dict:
    # i is now equal to (3, 13), or (11, 4) etc
    x, y = i
```

In fact you can do it in one step:

```
for x, y in dict:
    # etc.
```

However, for this manipulation, since it looks like you are wanting all the keys and values, I would use `dict.items()`, which returns key/values pairs:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    # You don't need to do dict.get anymore, you already have it: 
    if value == 'gas':
        list.append(key)
```

But you will also want to combine that with the tuple unpacking for the keys, so you end up with:

```
for (x, y), value in dict.items()
```

Another note: don't call a variable `list` or `dict` - these are builtins which will be shadowed

Answer (score 0):

Unpack a paired tuple into individual components during iteration. Then pass them in as arguments:

```
for x, y in dic.keys():
    formula(x, y)
```

Comment: You can just iterate over the dictionary itself, there is no need to call `.keys()` here. `for x, y in dic:`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True, just a preference I guess.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But then again, *explicit is better than implicit.* I'd rather think to myself that I am iterating the set of keys from a dictionary not the dictionary itself.

Comment: The documentation explicitly mentions that iteration over dictionaries yields keys, there is nothing implicit about this. Calling `.keys()` in Python 2 produces a new list object (very costly), and creating a dictionary view in Python 3 isn't free either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How about the efficiency of `iterkeys`?

Comment: Same thing; an attribute has to be looked up, called, a separate object is created, and *then* iteration takes place, vs. direct iteration. `dict.iterkeys()` is there for symmetry, I have yet to find a use for it.